# How to scroll Element in browser screen without scrolling complete browser window in Robot framework selenium

Tags: python, html-table, scroll, robotframework

I need to scroll a table in browser to left until its column LP is visible. I tried used java script executer for it but it didnt worked proeprly

I have tried below java script executer function

`Scroll Left Until Column Is Visible`
`[Arguments]     ${table_locator}    ${column_locator}`
`${table_ele}=       Get WebElement      ${table_locator}`
`${column_ele}=      Get WebElement      ${table_locator}`
`LOG     ${column_ele}`
`Sleep   10s`
`Execute JavaScript    arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});     ${column_ele}`

`Its giving me error JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')`
`(Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.71)`
`Stacktrace:`
`GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C62782B2+55298]`

Comment: Haven't you tried the keyword `Scroll Element Into View`? [Selenium Library](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Scroll%20Element%20Into%20View)

Comment: I have tried Scroll Element Into View    ${column_locator}  but it didnt worked. I don't want to scroll whole browser page . There is one  div element containing table  that I need to scroll until List price column has been shown